# When should I use the "Not an Answer" flag?

Tags: discussion, faq, flagging, moderators

Seems like there have been a few extra declined NAA flags lately so I would like to remind folks of the proper usage of this flag.

Answer (score 7):

The flag is titled, "Not an Answer", it isn't "Not THE Answer" which is the primary issue I've seen.  Poor answers should be downvoted, perhaps commented.  Flags aren't necessary.

I've copied the below from an excellent [meta.stackexchange answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/185073/how-do-i-properly-use-the-not-an-answer-flag).

### When should I use this flag?

Use this flag when an answer is being used to:

- Ask a new question
- Clarify the existing question
- Communicate with another user
- Say "thanks" or confirm that another posted answer worked for them
- "Bump" the question, as in "I have the same problem, have you found a solution?"

### When should I not use this flag?

Do not use this flag when:

- The user posts a partial answer
- The answer makes an attempt to answer the question, even if it is wrong or inaccurate or you disagree with it
- The problem with the answer is subtle and would benefit from additional explanation (see below)

### But I'm still not sure if I'm using the flag correctly...

If it seems blatantly obvious to you that what you're looking at isn't an answer, you're probably using the flag correctly.

If the problem is subtle and may not be obvious to whoever reviews your flag, then raise the *in need of moderator intervention* flag instead, and explain in detail why you think the answer violates the site rules and should thus be removed.

Comment: Every now and then we have a new user apparently mistake this place for a forum and use the answer space to not answer but instead just opine on the topic ([this deleted rant is a recent example](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/a/42881/5573)) or go on off some discussion tangent ("this game is so great and my family loved playing this game during camping trips and here's a story about this one time we played"). We'd flag those as NAA as well right, going by that second last paragraph of yours?

Comment: @doppelgreener - I don't think that explicitly triggers any of the bulletpoints in the first section, but it does seem blatantly obvious that it isn't an answer.  Flag away in similar circumstances. Although, I'd note that the MtG tag is largely self policing due to the large number of high rep users there.  The problems I see are mainly outside of that tag.

Comment: Thanks Pat. Could you clarify in this post what to do if it is an answer to a question that wasn't asked (i.e. it reads like an answer, but it doesn't answer what the OP actually asked)? I *think* that comes under "the problem is subtle" and hence *flag for mod attention with explanation*. But it could be "downvote and comment why you're downvoting, but no need to flag".

Comment: When determining whether or not the problem is subtle, can I assume that the reviewer has at least a basic understanding of the game in question? What is subtle to you may be blatantly obvious to anyone who has ever played the game even once.